# The merge cannot be completed because the divergence between the branches is too great. If you want to merge these branches, use a Git client

Tags: git, version-control, aws-codecommit

Alright, I'm using CodeCommit for my Remote-VCS and I'm seeing the error when trying to merge beta into stage.

I have tried merging them locally, but the issue remains intact.

REASON OF THE ISSUE: I haven't been pushed my changes to stage for a long a time, and kept adding new changes to beta. So, the divergence seems to be too great for CodeCommit to manage, I guess.

Please suggest me a good way to resolve this issue?

Thanks in Advance.

I'm expecting both my branches to be merged easily. So, I'm trying to look at logic and commands to resolve the divergence and merge them.

Comment: The error says "use a Git client [to merge]" – Have you tried that? It sounds like a good way to do the merge. If not, why not? If yes, why didn't it work?

Comment: Well, I cloned both the branches and tried merging them locally, and it showed the same error.

Comment: Git showed the error "If you want to merge, use a Git client"? I doubt that (this error message does not exist in Git)

Comment: Obviously, it didn't show me the exact same error, how come git client could even say that xD. But, yeah it sure had the problem.

Comment: It's impossible to help if the question does not contain all the relevant information (commands used, _exact_ error message, perhaps even a snippet of `git log --oneline --decorate --graph HEAD...branch-to-merge`). For now, I am voting to close with "needs details". Please [edit] your question to make it answerable